# How can I expand a dataframe which has 1 line to hundreds of times of it

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to expand a dataframe which only has 1 line to hundreds of times (330 exactly)of it. Is there any way to do that easily? All lines are the same.

A dataframe like this:

```
     f_date     f_open  f_close  f_high  f_low  f_volume  pre_date  pre_open  \
0  2019-01-21    24.5     24.5    24.5   24.5       0.0  2019-01-18     24.55

   pre_close  pre_high  pre_low  today_open  today_volumn  today_close  \
0       24.5     24.62    24.11        24.5           0.0         24.5

   pre_rate
0       0.0
```

I want to make it 330 times bigger and all lines are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
pd.concat([df] * 330)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.concat([df]*330, ignore_index=True)
```

the default ignore_index is set to False so if you don't set it to True you will have duplicate index "0" 330 times